# How can I select the country within which I map networks of country name co-mentions using GDELT?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am accessing the GDELT global news database on BigQuery.  I have some SQL code that has generated an adjacency list of countries that are co-mentioned.  This result was for all global news combined.  My problem is that I want to restrict the result to the news stories originating in one country, so I can compare two or more countries' networks of co-mentioned countries.

Here is the query output:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BBxUC9SRFAeBEo5AyX4EYgtK92VMmcEK9DLxte2Xhhk/edit?usp=sharing

FYI, here is a network graph of the output:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/101h4_kgbfOBGAakqPR-x6dVvObxKwvI6/view?usp=sharing

```
SELECT c.Source SourceCountryCode, d.country Source, c.Target TargetCountryCode, e.country Target, Count RawCount, "Undirected" Type, RATIO_TO_REPORT(Count) OVER () Weight FROM (
SELECT a.name Source, b.name Target, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM (FLATTEN(
SELECT GKGRECORDID, UNIQUE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(SPLIT(V2Locations,';'),r'^[1- 
5]#.*?#(.*?)#')) name
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
WHERE DATE > 20190101000000 and DATE < 20190605000000 AND V2Locations like '%United States%United States%' and (V2Themes like '%CYBER_ATTACK%' or DocumentIdentifier like '%cyber_attack%') ignore case
,name)) a
JOIN EACH (
SELECT GKGRECORDID, UNIQUE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(SPLIT(V2Locations,';'),r'^[1-5]#.*?#(.*?)#')) name
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
WHERE DATE > 20190101000000 and DATE < 20190605000000 AND V2Locations like '%United States%United States%' and (V2Themes like '%CYBER_ATTACK%' or DocumentIdentifier like '%cyber_attack%') ignore case
) b
ON a.GKGRECORDID=b.GKGRECORDID
WHERE a.name<b.name
GROUP EACH BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 1000
) c
JOIN EACH (
select fips, country from [gdelt-bq:extra.countryinfo]) d
ON c.Source = d.fips
JOIN EACH (
select fips, country from [gdelt-bq:extra.countryinfo]) e
ON c.Target = e.fips
order by Count Desc
```

Comment: I have tried inserting this into the WHEREs: DocumentIdentifier contains 'http' having countrycode = 'US'.  I get  an error code saying countrycode is not found.  Trying to find how to add countrycode to SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below to the bottom of query (but above `ORDER BY` obviously)

```
WHERE c.Source = 'US'
```

Also last two joins can be rewritten to be less verbose

```
JOIN EACH [gdelt-bq:extra.countryinfo] d 
ON c.Source = d.fips
JOIN EACH [gdelt-bq:extra.countryinfo] e
ON c.Target = e.fips
```